# Convert hive functions to java - translate and regexp_replace

Tags: java, regex, parsing, hadoop, hive

1) How do I convert the hive part below to java map reduce?

```
 translate(regexp_replace(colA,"(\\\\=)","\\\\equalto"),"\[\]\(\)\{\}\^\?\+\*\$","____________")
```

In the regexp_replace, I'm replacing all =, in the outer translate, I'm replacing all characters that affect future regexp_replace parses.(If I don't replace these characters, they raise an exception later).

2) Do I have to use replaceChars(), if yes, then how?

Sample string format is:

`tag1=573 tag2=ABC 0nuif6d Saturn 0i899 AA 0 (WORD) LOWER 0 (WORD2) HH 0 BB 0 CC 1 LL 0 D 0 FF 0 AB 0 UPPER 0 (ONCOLD) UPPER 1 PART: Sold \= 88vb JJ number\= 0 String "String_here" ANDND JUJFNG fill EXTRA SUNSET: empty tag3=/Informational tag4=/Value tag5=Value1/Value2 tag6=/AB/Acs Sy/Api Afg Hold Cones/HHH+11: 4.3.2-4.3.4 tag6=11123 tag7=Hello World tag8=a-dfdAds\=\= tag9=Value3 tag.9=Space separated words \= 88 , cold 87 Goal Run\=2, LOT OF SPACE SEPARATED GARBAGE WORDS tag.a=0( tag.b=02`

Note: Tags are not hardcoded as tags. They can be any english words like serial_number or website.address like `serial_no=hello world website.address=\SO.com=/question` where `serial_no` and `website.address` are tags.

Comment: Can you provide some sample text to help us understand exactly what you're starting with and what you'd like as the final product?

Comment: Okay. Sample string format is..(You can ignore the quotes)...:

    'tag1=573 tag2=ABC 0nuif6d Saturn 0i899 AA 0 (WORD) LOWER 0 (WORD2) HH 0 BB 0 CC 1 LL 0 D 0 FF 0 AB 0 UPPER 0 (ONCOLD) UPPER 1 PART: Sold \= 88vb JJ number\= 0 String "String_here" ANDND JUJFNG fill EXTRA SUNSET: empty tag3=/Informational tag4=/Value tag5=Value1/Value2 tag6=/AB/Acs Sy/Api Afg Hold Cones/HHH+11: 4.3.2-4.3.4 tag6=11123 tag7=Hello World tag8=a-dfdAds\=\= tag9=Value3 tag.9=Space separated words \= 88 , cold 87 Goal Run\=2, LOT OF SPACE SEPARATED GARBAGE WORDS tag.a=0( tag.b=02'

Comment: I want to extract all tags and have them tab separated 'tag \t value'. For this, I'm replacing all '\=' with '\equalto' , then removing all the special characters that cause regex to fail, then splitting by =, then getting the last word of each split and those are my tags, then for the value I'm replacing last word in each part with empty string "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This expression will:

- assume tag names contain no spaces
- assume tag names  are separated from their respective values by a `=` which has no white space on either side of the `=` symbol and is not proceeded by a `\`
- assume tag names are seperated from the preceeding string with white space, likewise values will be seperated from the next tag name by whitespace
- capture the tag name and value
- will avoid breaking the string up on equal signs which are embedded in the value side of the string

`(\S*?)(?<!\\)=(\S*.*?)(?=\S*(?<!\\)=|\Z)`

[image]

You can then reassemble or further process the individual components of the string as you see fit.

## Example

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/NlR1Iext9U)

**Sample Text**

From the sample text you included in the comments. It's not really clear what defines a tag or the equal sign for separating the name form the value:

`serial_no=hello world website.address=\SO.com=/question
tag1=573 tag2=ABC 0nuif6d Saturn 0i899 AA 0 (WORD) LOWER 0 (WORD2) HH 0 BB 0 CC 1 LL 0 D 0 FF 0 AB 0 UPPER 0 (ONCOLD) UPPER 1 PART: Sold \= 88vb JJ number\= 0 String "String_here" ANDND JUJFNG fill EXTRA SUNSET: empty tag3=/Informational tag4=/Value tag5=Value1/Value2 tag6=/AB/Acs Sy/Api Afg Hold Cones/HHH+11: 4.3.2-4.3.4 tag6=11123 tag7=Hello World tag8=a-dfdAds\=\= tag9=Value3 tag.9=Space separated words \= 88 , cold 87 Goal Run\=2, LOT OF SPACE SEPARATED GARBAGE WORDS tag.a=0( tag.b=02`

**Sample Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(\\S*?)(?<!\\\\)=(\\S*.*?)(?=\\S*(?<!\\\\)=|\\Z)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);

  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Matches**

Group 0 will have the entire substring
Group 1 will have the name field
Group 2 will have the value field

```
[0][0] = serial_no=hello world 
[0][1] = serial_no
[0][2] = hello world 

[1][0] = website.address=\SO.com=/question
[1][1] = website.address
[1][2] = \SO.com=/question

[2][0] = tag1=573 
[2][1] = tag1
[2][2] = 573 

[3][0] = tag2=ABC 0nuif6d Saturn 0i899 AA 0 (WORD) LOWER 0 (WORD2) HH 0 BB 0 CC 1 LL 0 D 0 FF 0 AB 0 UPPER 0 (ONCOLD) UPPER 1 PART: Sold \= 88vb JJ number\= 0 String "String_here" ANDND JUJFNG fill EXTRA SUNSET: empty 
[3][1] = tag2
[3][2] = ABC 0nuif6d Saturn 0i899 AA 0 (WORD) LOWER 0 (WORD2) HH 0 BB 0 CC 1 LL 0 D 0 FF 0 AB 0 UPPER 0 (ONCOLD) UPPER 1 PART: Sold \= 88vb JJ number\= 0 String "String_here" ANDND JUJFNG fill EXTRA SUNSET: empty 

[4][0] = tag3=/Informational 
[4][1] = tag3
[4][2] = /Informational 

[5][0] = tag4=/Value 
[5][1] = tag4
[5][2] = /Value 

[6][0] = tag5=Value1/Value2 
[6][1] = tag5
[6][2] = Value1/Value2 

[7][0] = tag6=/AB/Acs Sy/Api Afg Hold Cones/HHH+11: 4.3.2-4.3.4 
[7][1] = tag6
[7][2] = /AB/Acs Sy/Api Afg Hold Cones/HHH+11: 4.3.2-4.3.4 

[8][0] = tag6=11123 
[8][1] = tag6
[8][2] = 11123 

[9][0] = tag7=Hello World 
[9][1] = tag7
[9][2] = Hello World 

[10][0] = tag8=a-dfdAds\=\= 
[10][1] = tag8
[10][2] = a-dfdAds\=\= 

[11][0] = tag9=Value3 
[11][1] = tag9
[11][2] = Value3 

[12][0] = tag.9=Space separated words \= 88 , cold 87 Goal Run\=2, LOT OF SPACE SEPARATED GARBAGE WORDS 
[12][1] = tag.9
[12][2] = Space separated words \= 88 , cold 87 Goal Run\=2, LOT OF SPACE SEPARATED GARBAGE WORDS 

[13][0] = tag.a=0( 
[13][1] = tag.a
[13][2] = 0( 

[14][0] = tag.b=02
[14][1] = tag.b
[14][2] = 02
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I did not do a good job of displaying a sample string. Thank you for your answer though. The tag is not hard coded as tag, it can be any english word, say 'serial_no=hello world website.address=\SO.com=/question' where serial_no and website.address are tags.

Comment: I don't think a regex can be built to handle this?

Comment: That was brilliant! It works. I'll work more on it and let you know in case there are any problems. Thank you. PS: How do I start building the skill to make such regular expressions?

Comment: Cool. Getting better with regular expressions takes a bit of practice and some learning. I recommend starting with this site http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html as they have some really great (and concise) explanations. Once you know the basics, then you just have to learn the differences between how each language implemented their version of regular expressions.

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to open a new question on StackOver Flow. That expression is might not be valid and would need to have the `]` character escaped.